# Laravel 8 - API, pagination and resource. "links" obj into "meta" key

Tags: api, pagination, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 to build a simple API with paginated JSON.

The output contains a "links" object into "meta" key:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      . . .
    },
    {
      . . .
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "prev": null,
    "first": "http://localhost/api/my-api?&page=1",
    "next": null,
    "last": "http://localhost/api/my-api?&page=2"
  },
  "meta": {
    "from": 1,
    "per_page": 400,
    "total": 477,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 2,
    "path": "http://localhost/api/my-api",
    "to": 400,
    "links": [
      {
        "url": null,
        "label": "Previous",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://localhost/api/my-api?&page=1",
        "label": 1,
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "url": "http://localhost/api/my-api?&page=2",
        "label": 2,
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://localhost/api/my-api?&page=2",
        "label": "Next",
        "active": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've not found any documentation about it; also, the official documentation doesn't report it:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#pagination

How can I remove the "links" object?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit of trickery as we don't want to touch the source code. In your `Http/Controller/Api/V1` map or wherever your API collection classes exists, create a file called `PaginateResourceResponseExtended.php`. Add this code to the file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\PaginatedResourceResponse;

class PaginateResourceResponseExtended extends PaginatedResourceResponse
{
    /**
     * Gather the meta data for the response.
     *
     * @param  array  $paginated
     * @return array
     */
    protected function meta($paginated)
    {
        return Arr::except($paginated, [
            'data',
            'first_page_url',
            'last_page_url',
            'prev_page_url',
            'next_page_url',
            'links' //<----- THIS!
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your resource collection class, which is an extension to `ResourceCollection` add this:
`use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\PaginateResourceResponseExtended;`

Inside your class you can override a `ResourceCollection` method called `preparePaginatedResponse`:

```
public function preparePaginatedResponse($request)
{
    if ($this->preserveAllQueryParameters) {
        $this->resource->appends($request->query());
    } elseif (! is_null($this->queryParameters)) {
        $this->resource->appends($this->queryParameters);
    }

    return (new PaginateResourceResponseExtended($this))->toResponse($request);
}
```

Et voilà!

Of course you could also extend the `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;` class, change the method as described above and extend this to all your resource collections.

The protected `meta` method in `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\PaginatedResourceResponse` is what you want to change by simply adding `'links'` to the Array exceptions.

Just cross fingers the Laravel source files methods you override don't change in the next Laravel version

Answer (score 1):

Use `simplePaginate()` to achieve the same sample as in the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#simple-pagination